# C# - is it possible to modify values and call functions while the process is running?

Tags: c#

I've been starting to do some decompiling of my C# programs and got some interesting results by editing the dlls, but is it possible to change values and call functions in a running process given that I know what the names of the variables or functions are?

Comment: This concept is called “instrumentation”. You can look it up online. Instrumenting code with function calls is possible but doing it dynamically at IL level will be very difficult.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I don't think OP is asking about "instrumentation" (pre-process binaries to allow information collection), but rather modifying process memory and calling methods from other process without modifying binaries in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't any cheat to any game do exactly that?

I mean, if I understand you correctly, there is software called
[Cheat Engine](https://www.cheatengine.org/) which allows you to modify process variables values, inject dll's and much more.

Comment: hmm, I would rather not mess with addressing that's the thing, decompiling and playing with dlls was so easy compared to what I tried to do with cheat engine. Can I inject the DLL so that it would call functions relating to the process? changing values and calling functions? Can Cheat Engine do that?

Comment: Im almost certain it can, but sadly I cannot provide you much more details about how to achieve this because of my lack of experience with this software.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I'll google if it can